# Ant attributes duplication for javac

Tags: ant, javac, code-duplication

I have an Ant build with a lot of javac tasks.
I want all of them to be executed with the following attributes:

```
debug = "true" debuglevel = "lines,vars,source"
```

(by default debugging information is turned off which makes it harder to investigate the console).

Is it possible to provide such attributes in some centralized place which will have influence for all javac tasks in current Ant build? (I don't want duplicating them over all javac tasks...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ant's [presetdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/presetdef.html)

From the example

```
<presetdef name="my.javac">
   <javac debug="${debug}" deprecation="${deprecation}"
          srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
      <src path="${gen.dir}"/>
   </javac>
</presetdef>
```

Instead of `my.javac`, you can put `javac`.

You can define this in one build file and import every where else.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean, I'll need to add such a preset, and replace my javac tasks by my.javac?

Comment: see my update.  You can  have taskname as new name for preset. I did this for jar, should work for javac too

Comment: Great, I'll try this and tell the results!

Comment: Thanks, the `<presetdef name = "javac">
    <javac debug = "true" debuglevel = "lines,vars,source"/> 
 </presetdef>` works perfect!